# I'm new to programming and I successfully installed XAMPP but when I run the Admin on MySQL, local host refuses to connect

Tags: mysql, installation, xampp, localhost

This site can’t be reachedlocalhost refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

This is the message that popped up

Comment: Have you tried checking for a used proxy or whether your firewall is up as stated in the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the port first. Is your port is listening correctly or there may be a firewall preventing you to connect to that port.

You can use the following command to check the open ports
`sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN`

To check the specific port use
`sudo lsof -i:22` *see a specific port such as 22*